# Binary Tree Path Sum

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

Please check my code, I want fellow my idea to finish this question:
Your are given a binary tree in which each node contains a value. Design an algorithm to get all paths which sum to a given value. The path does not need to start or end at the root or a leaf, but it must go in a straight line down.
My code:

```
/**
 * Definition of TreeNode:
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     public int val;
 *     public TreeNode left, right;
 *     public TreeNode(int val) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = this.right = null;
 *     }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    /**
     * @param root the root of binary tree
     * @param target an integer
     * @return all valid paths
     */
    public List<List<Integer>> binaryTreePathSum2(TreeNode root, int target) {
        // Write your code here
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (root == null) {
            return result;
        }
        int sum = root.val;
        helper(root, target, sum, path, result); 
        return result;
    }
    private void helper(TreeNode root, 
                        int target,
                        int sum,
                        List<Integer> path,
                        List<List<Integer>> result) {
        if (root.val == target) {
            path.add(root.val);
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(path));
        }
        if (sum == target) {
            path.add(root.val);
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(path));
        } else if (sum < target) {
            path.add(root.val);
            if (root.left != null) {
                helper(root.left, target, sum + root.left.val, path, result);
            }
            if (root.right != null) {
                helper(root.right, target, sum + root.right.val, path, result);
            }
            if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
                path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            }
        } else if (sum > target) {
            sum = sum - root.val;
            if (root.left != null) {
                helper(root.left, target, sum + root.left.val, path, result);
            }
            if (root.right != null) {
                helper(root.right, target, sum + root.right.val, path, result);
            }
            if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
                 path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Input
See representation of a Binary Tree
{1,2,3,4,#,2}, 6
Output
[[1,3,2]]
Expected
[[1,3,2],[2,4]]

At this time, My code output is wrong answer, I can not find where is problem in my code.

Comment: The link you posted requires a userid to access it.  Based on my experience so far on StackOverflow, posting links is frowned upon.  Just describe the problem in your question.

Comment: Is this homework? You should debug your code.

Comment: Please describe your algorithm shortly. What is the expected run time?

Comment: When the value of current node causes the sum to increase beyond the target, you are removing the value of the current node from the sum, and continuing by searching its children.  This is incorrect according to the definition of the problem.

Comment: This is not homework.. just personal training personal training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got soulation by myself.

```
public void helper(TreeNode root, int sum, ArrayList<Integer> path, int level, List<List<Integer>> results) {
    if (root == null) return;
    int tmp = sum;
    path.add(root.val);
    for (int i = level;i >= 0; i--) {
        tmp -= path.get(i);
        if (tmp == 0) {
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int j = i; j <= level; ++j)
                temp.add(path.get(j));
            results.add(temp);
        }
    }
    findSum(head.left, sum, path, level + 1, results);
    findSum(head.right, sum, path, level + 1, results);
    buffer.remove(buffer.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: level initial value is 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I have modified your solution to fix the problem you raised, and also another problem which you might not have run into yet.  The second problem is: given a tree [1,2,3,4,#,2,#,#,#,#,#,1] your current algorithm will not find the additional solution [3,2,1] after it finds the initial solution [1,3,2].  I've also added a `println` statement to list the arguments of `helper` every time it is called, but you can delete that, as it's only helpful to see how the recursion operates.  The `main` method I've included tests the solution with two trees containing paths that your original solution would not have found:

```
public class Solution {
    /**
     * @param root
     *            the root of binary tree
     * @param target
     *            an integer
     * @return all valid paths
     */
    public List<List<Integer>> binaryTreePathSum2(TreeNode root, int target) {
        // Write your code here
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (root == null) {
            return result;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        helper(root, target, sum, path, result);
        return result;
    }

    private void helper(TreeNode root, int target, int sum, List<Integer> path, List<List<Integer>> result) {
        System.out.print("helper(root=" + root.val);
        System.out.print(",target=" + target);
        System.out.print(",sum=" + sum);
        System.out.print(",path=" + path);
        System.out.print(",result=" + result);
        System.out.println(")");

        sum += root.val;  // Update sum so it includes current root
        path.add(root.val);  // Add current node to the path 

        // To store nodes removed from the start of the current path
        List<Integer> startNodes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // If we've exceeded the target by adding the current node, then remove
        // nodes from the head of the path until the sum is <= the target
        while (sum > target) {
            // Remove node from start of path
            Integer head = path.remove(0);
            // Add removed node to startNodes list (to be added back later)
            startNodes.add(head);
            // Subtract the sum of the head
            sum -= head;
        }
        // If we've found a path that sums up to target
        if (sum == target) {
            // Add this path to the result
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(path));
            // Remove the head of this path so we can continue looking for other paths 
            Integer head = path.remove(0);
            // Add removed node startNodes list (to be added back later)
            startNodes.add(head);
            // Subtract the sum of the head, and continue
            sum -= head;
        }
        // sum < target, so continue finding other nodes
        if (root.left!=null) {
            helper(root.left,target,sum,path,result);
        }
        if (root.right != null) {
            helper(root.right,target,sum,path,result);
        }
        // remove current node from path before returning
        path.remove(path.size()-1);

        // If we had to remove nodes from start of path, add them back now
        // add it back again
        if (!startNodes.isEmpty()) {
            path.addAll(startNodes);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1);
        root.left = new TreeNode(2);
        root.right = new TreeNode(3);
        root.left.left = new TreeNode(4);
        root.right.left = new TreeNode(2);
        root.right.left.left = new TreeNode(1);
        Solution s = new Solution();
        List<List<Integer>> result = s.binaryTreePathSum2(root, 6);
        for (List<Integer> path : result) {
            System.out.println(path.toString());
        }
        TreeNode root2 = new TreeNode(1);
        root2.left = new TreeNode(1);
        root2.left.left = new TreeNode(1);
        root2.left.left.left = new TreeNode(5);
        result = s.binaryTreePathSum2(root2, 6);
        for (List<Integer> path : result) {
            System.out.println(path.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized this solution will not work in general either. I think I have an idea on how to fix it.

Comment: I've fixed it, and added an example tree to the `main` method that includes a tree with a path that my original solution would not have found.

Comment: Thanks David, nice try, but still have some problem when input tree is {1,-2,#,1,#,2}, target is 2, your code output is [[1,-2,1,2]], but expect output is [[1,-2,1,2],[2]]. looks like  the problem is same as my code, code not create second ArrayList object. I will keep going to try to find how to fix that :)

Comment: I didn't know you allow negative values.  You didn't mention this in the problem statement.

Comment: What format are you using to represent the tree?  I thought you were using something similar to a complete tree, but if I use that representation, `{1,-2,#,1,#,2}` is not a valid tree.

Comment: Alternatively, you can show me the code that constructs the tree you're talking about, e.g.,   `root = new TreeNode(a); root.left = new TreeNode(b); root.right = new TreeNode(c); root.right.left = new TreeNode(d) ;...`

Comment: Yes,question not tell us tree can be inculde negative values, look like we need consider any situation that may arise. Input tree looks like fellow pre-order.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `fellow pre-order`

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Regardless of the particular tree, to handle negative values, you'd have to completely change your algorithm.  What you have isn't even close to what you'd need. Basically, you'd have to traverse the whole tree using depth-first search, adding nodes to the path as you go deeper into the tree, and removing nodes as you backed out of a level.  When you reach a leaf node, you'll have a list of nodes going from the root to that leaf. Hand this list to another function that calculate all possible sums from that list.